# OSError: [WinError 1] Incorrect function

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller, oserror

help me, i can't use pyinstaller with matplotlib
,[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckNpt.png)

```
  File "quanlysinhvien.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 890, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 567, in matplotlib_fname
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 564, in gen_candidates
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 273, in wrapper
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 510, in get_configdir
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 465, in _get_config_or_cache_dir
  File "pathlib.py", line 1161, in resolve
  File "pathlib.py", line 205, in resolve
OSError: [WinError 1] Incorrect function: 'R:\\tmp097e8jcr'
```

and here is my spec file

```
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(
    ['quanlysinhvien.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=['sklearn.utils._typedefs'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=None,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=None)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='quanlysinhvien',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon='quanlysinhvien.ico',
)
```

i also use sklearn for my application and it doesn't give any error until i add matplotlib, and here is my
[import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvc2d.png)
I have tried all the methods I know but still no success, please help me

Comment: I just came across this error too when trying to run something, and I also have my temp drive set to `R`. By any chance are you using a ramdisk? I wonder if that's somehow related.

Answer (score 1):

If your script is on a RAM drive, as Peter asks, move it to a regular one and it may get fixed. Thanks to Peter for mentioning RAM disk!

I just had the same error on Windows with another library (streamlit), which strangely couldn't find the script as if the path was wrong (it was correct). That solution fixed that error.

Now I recalled that RUST also has errors when you try to build on a RAM drive (in order to reduce the writing on an SSD because it produces too much files).

The reason is that it seems some (or the free, e.g. Imdisk, OSFMount) RAM drives on Windows do not implement all standards, POSIX or whatever and they do not support some file functions. I guess there are no such problems on Linux where RAM drives are more "natural" artifacts, but I haven't tried.